# Using multiple getline calls to read multiple lines

Tags: c++, string, cin, getline

I'm using multiple `getline(cin, string)` calls to get two strings; however the code is skipping the second call and only handling the first.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        cout << "Please enter string A: " << endl;
        getline(cin, stringA);
    }

    if (i == 1)
    {
        cout << "Please enter string B: " << endl;
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, stringB);
    }
}
```

How do I change this to handle multiple getline() calls?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unable to reproduce bad behaviour with the code given. Bug may be elsewhere.

Regardless, the code can be a lot simpler and that may solve other problems:

```
cout << "Please enter string A: " << endl;
getline(cin, stringA);
cout << "Please enter string B: " << endl;
cin.ignore(); 
getline(cin, stringB);
```

The `for` loop allows you to eliminate duplicated code by repeating the same code over with small differences in parameters. There is no duplicated code, so `for` does nothing for you here.

Not sure what the goal of the `cin.ignore()` line is. It will discard the first  character of the second line of input. If that's what you want, groovy if not, reconsider.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling some form of `cin >> someString;` earlier in the code.

If so, it has probably left a newline in the input stream. Thus when the first `getline()` is called it will immediately stores this newline in `stringA` then waits for input for `stringB`. Consider either using `getline()` for all your inputs, or calling a "dummy" `getline()` after each time you use `cin >> ...;`. This dummy `getline()` will clear the input stream, avoiding this type of bug.

Comment: [Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction)

Answer (score -1):

have you been declared strings before it because it is working properly in my

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).